# Anyone with experience using both Sketch with Flinto or other prototyping software

Tags: interface-design, sketch-app

I'm interested in hearing from people, possibly starting a thread to discuss using a UI design workflow that starts with Sketch and uses Flinto for Mac, or some other prototyping software.  I'm trying to figure out my own workflow.  I love Sketch but haven't decided on a prototyping software yet.  I'm leaning towards Flinto for Mac because you are able to animate individual layers, or objects, using the Flinto Sketch plugin, that brings in layered artboards into Flinto.  If anyone has any experience with this, or another way of prototyping with Sketch assets.  I've seen youtube tutorial videos where people create something in Sketch and then export assets and have to recreate exactly what they did in Sketch already, and this seems insane.  If anyone has advice, I'd love to hear it.  If anyone is also comparing prototyping software, I'd love to hear about it.

In general, I'm interested in all the software a designer uses in a UI design workflow (including helper software like Zeplin) in order to produce prototypes and get apps and websites produced.  Lastly, if anyone has any advice on putting together a portfolio of interactive prototypes that can be shown to prospective employers/clients, I'd love to hear about that as well.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.pixate.com/ is an interesting one for layered animations like what you've mentioned. I've had some fun with it, but honestly my prototyping workhorse is http://www.invisionapp.com/

For client feedback / sharing, InVision is amazingly easy.  They've got Sketch art board support, and their own sync app (like G Drive or DropBox) that makes the workflow pretty nice.  I don't mean to sound like an advertisement for them, but the honestly have made life a lot easier for me.